# React Native nested Flatlist (horizontal flatlist inside vertical flatlist)

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-flatlist

I have a horizontal flatlist inside a vertical flatlist and I want data on the inside flatlist to be provided based on which item of the outer flatlist is being rendered

This is what I have currently:

```js
  <FlatList
    style={styles.outerFlatlist}
    data={this.state.catagories}

    renderItem={({item, index})=>{
return (
  <View>
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.catagoryName}>
        {item.CategoryName}
        </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.innerFlatlist}>
      <FlatList
      horizontal={true} 
      data={this.state.product1}
      renderItem={({item, index})=>{
          return (
          <View 
          style={styles.productsContainer}>
            <View
            style={styles.productImage}>
             <Image 
             source={{uri:item.productImage}}
             style={styles.image}
             resizeMode='contain'>
            </Image>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.productDETAILS}>
            <Text 
            style={styles.productPrice}>R{item.productPrice}
            </Text>
            <Text 
            style={styles.productDescription}> 
                 {item.productDecription}
            </Text>
          </View>
          </View>
          );
          }}/>
        </View>
    </View>
);
}}/>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

With the above code, everything works well except that each category displays the same data (this.state.product1), how can I make the data of the inner flatlist be dependant on the which item on the outer flatlist is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are inside the .map you already are inside the this.state.catagories , but since you always use this.state.product1 for the flatlist2 you will always get the same result because this.state.product1 **stays the same.**

At flatlist2 change the data to *item.products* or *item.whateverYouNeedHereButArray*

```
<View style={styles.innerFlatlist}>
      <FlatList
      horizontal={true} 
      data={item}
```